# In Ant, how do I get the return value from an exec?

Tags: ant

```
<target name="CheckState">
     <exec executable="${App.path}"/>
</target>
```

In this task, the executable will return a value which will indicate the state of my app. How could I get the value returned in the Ant build file.  I will use this value to determine some behaviour.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use the `resultproperty` and `failonerror` attributes of the [`exec`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) task, e.g.:

```
<target name="CheckState">
     <exec executable="${App.path}"
           resultproperty="App.state"
           failonerror="false"/>
     <echo message="App state was: ${App.state}" />
</target>
```

Quoting from the `exec` task docs *Errors and return codes*:

> By default the return code of an exec
>   is ignored; when you set
>   failonerror="true" then any return
>   code signaling failure (OS specific)
>   causes the build to fail.
>   Alternatively, you can set
>   resultproperty to the name of a
>   property and have it assigned to the
>   result code (barring immutability, of
>   course).
>
> If the attempt to start the program
>   fails with an OS dependent error code,
>   then  halts the build unless
>   failifexecutionfails is set to false.
>   You can use that to run a program if
>   it exists, but otherwise do nothing.
>
> What do those error codes mean? Well,
>   they are OS dependent. On Windows
>   boxes you have to look at the
>   documentation; error code 2 means 'no
>   such program', which usually means it
>   is not on the path. Any time you see
>   such an error from any Ant task, it is
>   usually not an Ant bug, but some
>   configuration problem on your machine.

Comment: Thanks. This works!I tried outputproperty and errorproperty, but didn't see resultproperty.

Comment: Did you have the fork property set to true? According to O'Reilly's _Ant: The Definitive Guide_, the resultproperty will only work if failonerror is false _and_ fork is true. However, fork seems to be an attribute of the Java element.

Comment: @Jamil I don't quite follow.  A fork is implicit in an exec - there's no need to specify it.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that we cannot run 2 consecutive exec with the *same* output property?  This immutability is driving me nuts...  I even tried the <var ...> ant contrib and it does not works either.  Any idea?

Answer (score 7):

Here is a generic way to check the result and display the output of the execution *only* if the process returns a failure code.

```
<property
    name="my.project.tmp.exec.output"
    value="${tmp.dir}/exec-output.txt"/>

<target
    name="my.project.my.task">
    <exec
        executable="${App.path}"
        output="${my.project.tmp.exec.output}"
        resultproperty="my.project.my.task.result"
        failonerror="false"/>
    <loadfile
        srcfile="${my.project.tmp.exec.output}"
        property="my.project.my.task.output"
    />
    <fail message="ERROR: ${my.project.my.task.output}">
        <condition>
            <not>
                <equals arg1="${my.project.my.task.result}" arg2="0"/>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </fail>
    <delete file="${my.project.tmp.exec.output}"/>
</target>
```