# get output from exec in ant build script in a netbeans project

Tags: apache, netbeans, ant, output

I´m running a macro in ant build script in a netbeans project and in this macro is called an exec operation. In the macro I can write something to a run console of the netbeans project, but what if I want to write something during executing the exec statement? Like output from the exec?

Thanks for answers,
O.

Answer (score 1):

Use the **resultproperty** property. This post explains it: [How to get a return value from an exec in ant script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344139/how-to-get-a-return-value-from-an-exec-in-ant-script)

Comment: so everything I write to console via the executed program will be displayed in ant script console?

Comment: I do not think you need any special handling for that. At least on the commandline, I get the output of the executed external commands automatically. Did you try it?

Comment: Actually I did not:) I've never thought that it can be this easy. I'll give it a try. thank you