# Ant apply for entire fileset and raise error at the end

Tags: ant, awk, jenkins

I have following job in my build.xml

```
<target name="doubleEmptyLines">
    <apply executable="awk" failonerror="true">
        <arg value="BEGIN{bl=0}/^$/{bl++;if(bl>1) { print &quot;Double empty lines dedected in&quot; FILENAME; exit 1}}/^..*$/{bl=0}"/>
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}">
            <include name="**/*.php" />
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </apply>
</target>
```

As you see it looks for double empty lines, for example between functions declaration. It is working fine, however it stops at first failure but I want it to continue trough entire fileset and throw error at the end if any file in fileset had error.

So I will may look to entire report and see every wrong file then fix all of them at once.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: Remove the `exit` that is there, set something like `errFlg=1` when your condition is found, and then add `END{if (errFlg) exit 1} (at the end of the awk script. Good luck.

Comment: @shelter but it will break the fileset loop anyway

Comment: What happens if you set `failonerror="false"`?

Comment: I doesn't throw error which means build will pass.

Comment: Ok, I am not familiar with `ant`.. But I think I am starting to understand your problem.. Maybe you could have a look at `resultproperty` of `exec` task? See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344139/how-to-get-a-return-value-from-an-exec-in-ant-script

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it this way:

```
<target name="doubleEmptyLines">
    <apply verbose="true" executable="awk" outputproperty="doubleEmptyLinesResult" append="true">
        <arg value="BEGIN{bl=0}/^$/{bl++;if(bl>1) { print &quot;ERROR: Double empty lines dedected in&quot; FILENAME NR &quot;\n&quot;; exit 1}}/^..*$/{bl=0}"/>
        <fileset dir="${sourcedir}">
            <include name="**/*.php" />
            <include name="**/*.js" />
        </fileset>
    </apply>

    <condition property="doubleEmptyLinesFound">
        <contains string="${doubleEmptyLinesResult}" substring="ERROR"/>
    </condition>

    <fail if="doubleEmptyLinesFound" message="Double lines found, output from script: ${doubleEmptyLinesResult}"/>
</target>
```