# Execute wmic command in ant target

Tags: ant, wmic

How to execute the below command in ant target with < exec > task.

```
wmic nic where 'netconnectionid like '%'' get netconnectionid
```

If I run above in command line, I can get this output:

```
NetConnectionID
Local Area Connection
Local Area Connection 2
```

However, if I call this command via this way:

```
<target name="test">
    <exec executable="wmic">
    <arg line="nic where 'netconnectionid like '%'' get netconnectionid"/>
    </exec>
</target>
```

I got below error:

```
[exec] Node - MyComputer
[exec] ERROR:
[exec] Description = Invalid query
[exec]
[exec]
[exec] Result: -2147217385
```

Anyone can help me?
Thank you!

Comment: Is this any help, use exec task and read output? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4344139/how-to-get-a-return-value-from-an-exec-in-ant-script

Comment: To me, the single quotes look suspicious. Are they suppose to show inner and outer quotes? You can use HTML entity `&quot;` for double quotes, and `&apos;` for single quotes. Will that help?

Answer (score 0):

80041017 is your error number. numbers greater than 80040200 are component specific errors (and a general OLE errors under 0x80040200).

WBEMDisp.h says this

```
wbemErrInvalidQuery = 0x80041017
```

But your query is for EVERYTHING, so you can omit your `where` alltogether.

```
wmic nic get netconnectionid
```